# What is a main difference between a plugin and a component in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

What is a main difference between a plugin and a component in extjs ?
When should I implement and use some behavior as a class and when as a plugin ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well that is more a conceptional question than related to any programming issue. But it can be answered in two sentences:

- A Plugin modifies or extend the behavior of a component at creation time without the need to extend the whole class
- Plugins can be mixed, meaning a component can include many plugins which allow you to instantiate many component instances where each may have different behavior but all uses the same component class

**Like [@A1rPun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1449624/a1rpun) mentioned**

> Plugins allow us to create **reusable** code that will modify or add to a
>   component's look and behavior during or **after** its instantiation.

Comment: Note that plugins are simply classes, in the same way all components are. "Plugins allow us to create reusable code that will modify or add to a component's look and behavior during or after its instantiation."

Answer (score 1):

- Components in ExtJS provide basic, required functionality. There are
  many components readily available like text box, combobox, grid,
  tree, panel, etc.
- Components can be used without using plugins also.
- Plugins add more functionality and/or look n feel to existing
  components. For example, ExtJS has grid component into which we
  can plug-in "drag and drop" plugin. Grid component can be used
  without drag and drop also.
- Plugins cannot be used independently without using Components.